# Misplaced noalign with datatool and booktabs

Tags: booktabs, datatool

I experience a (I’m afraid not so original) “Misplaced noalign” with the following example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{mydb}
\DTLnewrow{mydb}
\DTLnewdbentry{mydb}{column}{entry}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    top\\
    \DTLforeach*{mydb}{}{3\\}
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

```
Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.25 \bottomrule
```

and may many more errors that do not seem informative (`Missing \cr inserted`…).

The error disappears if commenting out the DTL line or replacing it with the content it should produce (namely, `3\\`).

I have observed that putting the `\\` first instead of last works around the problem. But this generally requires a conditional, using `\DTLiffirstrow`, as the result of the for each loop should generally not start with `\\` (e.g., in the typical case of `\DTLforeach` immediately following a `\toprule` command), and makes the code slightly more obscure.

I also expect that building the table out of the `tabular` environment (following a [common](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445403/vertical-spacing-with-cmidrule-with-datatool-table) [advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83466/equivalent-of-dtliflastrow)) would also solve the problem, but at the price of making the code much less readable.

I wonder if I’m doing anything wrong or if anything is wrong with my local installation, as this problem seems to be very seldom [observed](https://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?74251-datatool-in-tabular-ergibt-Misplaced-noalign) and the datatool manual suggest that it can be used [together with booktabs](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf#example.6). (I have seen some [similar error message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611786/misplaced-noalign-because-input-before-booktabs-rule) related to using booktabs, but I suspect my problem differs as I do not use the `\input` command.)

Both approaches feel more like working around the problem than solving it, IMHO. Therefore, my question is: is there a more elegant solution to this problem? (E.g. by patching some booktabs or DTL command in the preamble.)

Answer (score 6):

you are hiding the last \ inside the DTLforeach and this separates it from the \bottomrule. That doesn't work.

Build the rows outside the tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool,etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{mydb}
\DTLnewrow{mydb}
\DTLnewdbentry{mydb}{column}{entry}

\newcommand\tabrows{}
\DTLforeach*{mydb}{}{\appto\tabrows{3\\}}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    top\\
    \tabrows
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```